# mysql shell for vscode: runSql() function returns: failed to execute postmessage on dedicatedworkerglobalscope

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mysql-shell

I'm using `mysql shell for vscode` extension and typescript code like this documentation blow:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell-gui/en/mysql-shell-vscode-notebook-select-typescript.html

but I'm getting error showed in image blow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the data you're trying to send with postMessage is clonable. Functions, for instance, cannot be cloned and sent to web workers.